Android : How to change LOG OUTPUT LEVEL by cmd?
In Developer Options Android, how can i change LOG OUTPUT LEVEL from DEBUG to VERBOSE by adb command?
i used this cmd : "adb shell settings put global adb_log_level 1" but it did not worked. The log level in UI is still DEBUG
Thank you for your help

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
